# how to add seconds to time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering if it's possible to add seconds to a clock in vb.net. I mean lt's say I have a label and I assign it to DateTime.Now(), how would I show/display the time with the seconds "ticking"?

Comment: You will need a Timer. But please specify WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about ASP.NET and not a desktop app. In which case you're going to have to use JavaScript to update the user interface as once the time is set from the server side you can't update it. See this:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Comment: @Thanks Nico, I realized I had to use javascript for it. Just thought there was a way to update the time from server side.

Comment: Well, there is, but you would have to use AJAX to perform a "partial postback" that refreshes the area of the page containing your timer. It's guaranteed to be behind the true time because of data transmission latency if nothing else, and if you had even some dozen users with your site up, your web server would be crying uncle from updates every second.